# Some problems about the external Jar -- android-support-v13.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, android-viewpager

I want to implement the effect of switching between pages. Like the  Contracts in android 4.0, including AndroidBar ,Tab and ViewPager.

But when I create the android project by eclipse, it shows "your project contain errors,please fix them before running your application".

I had imported the jar from the android SDK to the project, the path is

```
  **\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v13\android-support-v13.jar**
```

The way to import the jar is this:

```
**project --> Properties --> Java build path --> 
  Libraries --> Add external JARs.. --> android-support-v13.jar --> OK**
```

But in the java code , the eclipse import following the code automatically

```
  **import com.example.android.supportv13.R;
    ...**
```

Then , I delete the import sentence which contains com.example .It's the same problem.

I had cleaned the project many times . It doesn't work.

Is the android-support-v13.jar file out of place ?

Thanks.

Comment: Dump the .jar file in your projects "libs" folder (create it if its not there) Done. It's automatically detected. Remove any references you previously added (like you described in your question)

Comment: Best bet is to use the v4 support library so you can support more devices with older versions of android.

Comment: Thanks .Useful suggestion !  But someone said the v13 is completely compatible !

Comment: It also doesn't work. I had done the step according to what you said( creating "libs" folder and removing the references).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to import the jar is this:

**project --> Properties --> Java build path --> 
  Libraries --> Add external JARs.. --> android-support-v13.jar --> OK**

Then clean the project and restart the eclipse .

It's OK.